# OpenAL: how can I create more than 2 or 3 stereo sources?

Tags: iphone, openal

I'm creating a context with

```
alcCreateContext(device, NULL).
```

The problem is that `ALC_STEREO_SOURCES` is **3** by default, so my program freezes if I try to reproduce more than 3 stereo sounds.

How can I set `ALC_STEREO_SOURCES` to **32**?

More info: I'm coding for the iOS platform, in Objective-C.

Comment: How many sources did you generate with alGenSources?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify context creation attributes by making an array of type ALCInt, containing ordered pairs of names and values.

So for example:

```
ALCInt myParams[3] = {ALC_STEREO_SOURCES, 32, 0};
alcCreateContext(myDevice, myParams);
```